# How do I append erb with jQuery in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do I append erb with jQuery in rails 4?

When I try:

```
$('.a_class').on 'click', (event) ->
    link =  '<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>'
    $(this).append(link)
```

I get the link_to code printed out as a string.

I have tried various combinations with .html() and .html_safe from other questions  but they don't seem to work. What does?

Comment: Your form probably outputs the link variable as text rather than as code. Post the portion of your form where you use the link variable.

Comment: make partial and use `$('selector').html('<%=render partial%>'

Comment: Which file is this code located in?